# How to make Mac OS X <Cmd-f> "find" feature local to application window

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, find, textedit

### Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

Sometimes I open up multiple windows of TextEdit and multiple tabs on Chrome and use the `Cmd-f` to find certain text. In each window, I'm looking for **different** texts. However, when I switch between the windows, the search text automatically transfers itself to the next window, and I lose my previous search results.

**How do I make `Cmd-f` search text local to the application window, and not transfer itself when I switch between windows?**

#### For example:

1. In Chrome - tab 1, I searched `chickens`. 300 results show up. I scrolled to the 150th.
2. In Chrome - tab 2, I searched `eggs`
3. When I switch back to tab 1, the search text automatically switches from `chickens` to `eggs`!

I have to enter `chickens` with `Cmd-f` all over again, and it might just start again from the 1st result, and I have to press `Enter` 149 times. So far this behavior has happened when switching between chrome tabs, between Chrome and TextEdit, and between TextEdit windows.

Comment: I don't think it's possible - search uses the kill-ring, rather than the regular copy/paste buffer - but there's only one of each, so whatever is in it is what you're going to be 'pasting' to the next field, even if you don't consider it related.

Comment: @Tetsujin Hmm. That is very unfortunate. I don't see why they designed it this way.

Comment: I think it's legacy... it might be possible to code round it, but as the copy buffers are system-wide, it might not be too easy.

Comment: Related: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1249590/macos-find-box-auto-change-across-app), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1320037/text-typed-into-different-apps-e-g-chrome-sublime-find-functions-cmd-f-ove)

Comment: Sad to see this problem is still active after 2 years (sigh). [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1320037/text-typed-into-different-apps-e-g-chrome-sublime-find-functions-cmd-f-ove) seems to provide more detailed context though.

Comment: This is terribly annoying, took me a while to find this thread. Glad I'm not the only one! Will listen for a fix.