# macOS find box auto change across app

Tags: macos-sierra

OS: macOS Sierra

Example1: Chrome has two tabs, cmd+F and type something like `search` to find in one tab, the text in the other tab's find box auto changes to `search`.

Example2: When I find something in Skype and Chrome at the same time, but with different text. If switch from one app to the other, the search text auto changes to the previous one.

Question: Is it a system provided feature? How to disable it?

Comment: Related: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1095883/how-to-make-mac-os-x-cmd-f-find-feature-local-to-application-window), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1320037/text-typed-into-different-apps-e-g-chrome-sublime-find-functions-cmd-f-ove)