# Text typed into different apps (e.g. Chrome, Sublime) find functions (Cmd-F) overwrites each other

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, find-and-replace, sublime-text-3

I'm seeing unusual behavior in the interaction between some Mac programs like Firefox, Safari, Sublime, and Chrome.  I'll concentrate on the last two.  I have a Macbook Pro (Retina, 13-in, mid-2014) running macOS 10.13.4; Chrome 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit); and Sublime 3.0 (build 3143).

Suppose I try searching for some text in a document using Sublime by pressing Cmd-F and typing `code`.   The text `code` appears in Sublime's Find box (bottom of window) and the window scrolls to highlight over the first instance in the document.  Then I switch focus to Chrome using Cmd-tab and try searching for some text on a webpage by pressing Cmd-F and typing `webtext`.  The text `webtext` appears in Chrome's Find box (upper-right corner) and the window scrolls to highlight over the first instance in the webpage.  Seem's OK so far.

However, when I switch focus back to Sublime, I find that `webtext` is now written in Sublime's Find box, erasing my previous search term `code`.  If I type in a new search like `code2` into Sublime's Find box, switching back to Chrome reveals it has likewise overwritten `webtext` there.

If I try repeating this with both the Chrome window and Sublime window visible at the same time, I find that the Find-box overwriting in the non-focused program doesn't occur until I switch focus to it with Cmd-Tab.

**What's going on, and how do I prevent this behavior?**

(None of this depends on whether I use keyboard shortcuts like Cmd-Tab or Cmd-F vs. selecting things from the menu with the mouse.  I see the same universal interaction with Safari and Firefox, but not Mathematica and Evernote.  Presumably there's some sort of OS-wide tool the offenders are using, and Mathematica and Evernote have custom searches.)

Comment: Ugh, dug these previous questions up: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/1249590/macos-find-box-auto-change-across-app), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1095883/how-to-make-mac-os-x-cmd-f-find-feature-local-to-application-window).

Comment: Just stumbled across this from Google... I can't believe this is still an issue over 5 years later. Slightly more info [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252599487) FYI.